# SqlServer 2012 - Column '' in table '' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2012

Depois de ver esse erro na hora de criar um índice NONCLUSTERED eu fiquei pensando se realmente seria necessário criar esse índice no seguinte cenário:

Tenho uma tabela com 11 colunas, uma coluna eu guardo uma URL, ou seja é uma coluna `nvarchar(300)`, essa coluna aceita valores nulls.

Em um determinado momento eu preciso fazer um SQL para pegar os valores da tabela onde essa coluna não é nula. Por isso pretendia criar um índice , para acelerar isso.

Estou usando EF6 e SQLServer 2012. Existe ganho em se criar um índice nesse cenário? Se existe como eu o criaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este índice não seria útil para este tipo de query que você descreveu.

> Não devemos criar índices para colunas cuja informação varia muito pouco entre os registros.

Por exemplo, não faz sentido criar um índice para uma coluna que contenha sempre ou zero ou um. É pouco provável que um índice como este seja usado pelo banco pois um *table scan* (percorrer a tabela inteira em vez de usar o índice) na maioria das vezes seria mais eficiente.

Como a sua consulta verifica apenas se a coluna é ou não é nula, o que está sendo verificado é se ela se encontra em um de apenas dois estados possíveis, ou seja, assim como no exemplo dos zeros e ums, é muito pouco provável que este índice seja utilizado pois o *table scan* geralmente terá melhor performance.

> Índices que não são utilizados nas consultas não deveriam ser criados pois apesar de não trazerem nenhum benefício ainda precisam ser mantidos pelo banco ou seja: ocupam espaço e consomem processamento.

Veja este artigo Microsoft para orientações gerais muito interessantes sobre o *design* de índices: [SQL Server Index Design Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx).

> Por fim, apesar de haver orientações gerais úteis, é sempre bom analisar o plano de execução das queries para identificar se em um cenário específico um índice deve ou não ser criado ou removido.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!